# Android-PHP-mysql other device can't write data

Tags: php, android, mysql

I have create an android app which use register and login at my website using PHP and mysql.
I have test it couple of time on my device and on emulator and it work just fine.

And then I ask my friend to try it on his device, but when he try to register(which is write data to mysql via php and json from his device, from his internet connection) it failed. The application hang for a while and then show warning app stop... or something like that...

What make this happen?
is it from php side which cause this? the file permission?
from mysql side?
or something else?

Answer (score 0):

Is the webserver at your location? Maybe it's a setting in the way you configured your settings. Make sure that your ports are forwarded correctly

Answer (score 0):

Please provide more information, improve your question, for example:

- Is your friend able to connect to the php website via a browser?
- Have you checked the log files of your web-server (is your friend actually connecting to your web server?)

You might try to debug data-traffic and check 'what' is going on by using a debugging proxy-tool, for example:
http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/